# How can i delete a file after complete download on client PC in MVC asp.net

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, download

i have used getCSV function for return csv file at client side but i want to delete a file after download complete at client side

my function

```
Public Function GetCSVFile(ByVal listSeperator As String) As CSVResult
    Dim result As Boolean
    Dim Service As New Service()
    Dim types As IList(Of ProductType) = Service.GetAllWithAllLocalizedNames(New ListOptions(Name", OrderByDirection.Ascending, 1, -1))
    Dim path As String, colname As String
    colname = Settings.GetLanguage()
    path = Common.GetLocalizeDataPath()
    Dim seprator As String = Common.GetListSepratorForCSV(listSeperator)
    Dim cs As New CSVGenerator(path, colname, seprator)
    result = cs.CreateCSVFile(types)
    If result Then
        Return New CSVResult With {.FileName = "Sample.csv", .Path = "~/Mydir/Sample.csv"}
    Else
        Return New CSVResult With {.FileName = "Error.csv", .Path = "~/Mydir/Error.csv"}
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 6):

Only works for me if you flush the response. Attribute filter should look like this

```
    public class DeleteTempFileResultFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
        {
            string fileName = ((FilePathResult)filterContext.Result).FileName;

            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Flush();
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.End();

            System.IO.File.Delete(fileName);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way would probably be to not actually save a file but to dump the csv directly into the response stream and then no file ever actually exists.

A similar question was discussed here:
[ASP.NET stream content from memory and not from file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946908/asp-net-stream-content-from-memory-and-not-from-file)

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help you. First you need to write the data to a file on server then use give option to client to download the file. after that use file.delete to remove the file from server

```
Response.ContentType = ContentType;
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename=myFile.txt");
Response.WriteFile(Server.MapPath("~/FilePath"));
Response.Flush();
System.IO.File.Delete(Server.MapPath("~/FilePath"));
Response.End();
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have written a custom `CSVResult` class. You can delete the file once you have written it to the response stream in the [ExecuteResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionresult.executeresult.aspx) method. Obviously a much better approach would be to never generate a file, but serve the CSV directly from memory and write it to the response stream.

Answer (score 0):

Creat a class and inherit form actionfilterattribute and override OnResultExecuted method

```
Public Class DeleteFileAttribute
    Inherits ActionFilterAttribute
    Public Overrides Sub OnResultExecuted(ByVal filterContext As ResultExecutedContext)
        Dim path As String = filterContext.HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/LocalizeData")
        Dim filename As String = DirectCast(filterContext.Result, CSVResult).FileName  'filterContext.RouteData.Values("Path").ToString()
        If File.Exists(System.IO.Path.Combine(path, filename)) Then
            File.Delete(System.IO.Path.Combine(path, filename))
        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```

and apply delete attribute on function

for example

```
<DeleteFile()>
Public Function GetCSVFile(ByVal listSeperator As String) As CSVResult
    Dim result As Boolean
    Dim Service As New Service()
    Dim types As IList(Of ProductType) = Service.GetAllWithAllLocalizedNames(New ListOptions(Name", OrderByDirection.Ascending, 1, -1))
    Dim path As String, colname As String
    colname = Settings.GetLanguage()
    path = Common.GetLocalizeDataPath()
    Dim seprator As String = Common.GetListSepratorForCSV(listSeperator)
    Dim cs As New CSVGenerator(path, colname, seprator)
    result = cs.CreateCSVFile(types)
    If result Then
        Return New CSVResult With {.FileName = "Sample.csv", .Path = "~/Mydir/Sample.csv"}
    Else
        Return New CSVResult With {.FileName = "Error.csv", .Path = "~/Mydir/Error.csv"}
    End If
End Function
```

and one more issue on execute result please flush the reponse and close it

```
context.HttpContext.Response.Flush()
context.HttpContext.Response.End()
```