# How to download instead of saving a Excel document c#

Tags: c#, excel

I am writing a Excel file based off user inputs. Currently it brings up a save dialog when the report is generated asking to replace the current one. My problem is this can be run on any machine. I figured to make things more simple I would just show the file as a download.

Commonly done like this:

```
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + filename);
Response.Charset = String.Empty;
Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
Response.End();
```

Only problem is it does not show the file that I made it shows a blank one it created. How can I get the download to show my created file? This is what I have currently.

```
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + filename);
Response.Charset = String.Empty;
Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
Response.End();

xlWorkBook.SaveAs(filename, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
xlApp.Quit();

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Users\LYNX\Documents\" + filename);

releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
releaseObject(xlApp);
```

I would like for the user to be able to just download the created file that way I do not have to declare a file path. If any other code is needed or clarification is needed please ask. Thank you.

Comment: The information in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/946988/61470) should help.